# Divs location changes if i remove the border

Tags: html, location, border

I have 3 divs. One inside the other. The first div(yellow background) has absolute width and height. The second div(green background) is located inside the first one and has 100% width and height. The last one(red background) that is located in the second one has the parameters to be centered horizontally and vertically. 
The problem is that everything works well only if the second div has a border.

Here is the code

```
<div  id="div1" style="width: 100; height: 70px; position: absolute;background-color:yellow;left: 10px; top: 20px; z-index: 2">
<div  id="div2" style='width:100%;height:100%;background-color:green;border: 3px solid black'>
<div id="div3" class="div_hover" style="width: 90px; height: 60px; position: relative; top: 50%; margin: -30px auto auto; border: 1px dashed rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color: red;">div with border
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The border in the second div is the following

```
border: 3px solid black
```

I don't need this border and if i remove it then then the location of my divs changes dramatically.

You can see the [screenshot](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/6416/borderlocation.jpg) or try the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pj5kP/2/)

Please, don't advice me to make the border invisible,transparent or something like that.

Help me, please, to keep the location of divs without using a border.
P.S User jvilhena advised me to use position:absolute for the second div. It fixes the problem but i can't use it for  my code. Please, advice me another way.

Comment: I see what you are saying. One moment.

Comment: it is a very strange behavior. I tried getting rid of the 2nd div background-color, and it seems to correct the alignment (after changing "width: 100;" with "width: 200px;" to make it more obvious). Do you need that background color?

Comment: I do need a background color for second div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the background of second div is somehow "moving" up, probably because of the margin: -30px of the third div (if you put them side by side you can see that). If you add a position:absolute to the second div, it fixes the problem:

```
<div  id="div1" style="width: 200px; height: 70px; position: absolute;background-color:yellow;left: 10px; top: 20px; z-index: 2">
<div  id="div2" style='width:100%;height:100%;background-color:green;border: 3px solid black'>
<div id="div3" class="div_hover" style="width: 90px; height: 60px; position: relative; top: 50%; margin: -30px auto auto; border: 1px dashed rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color: red;">div with border
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="div1" style="width: 200px; height: 70px; position: absolute;background-color:yellow;left: 250px; top: 20px; z-index: 2">
<div id="div2" style='width:100%;height:100%;background-color:green;position: absolute;'>
<div id="div3" class="div_hover" style="width: 90px; height: 60px; position: relative; top: 50%; margin: -30px auto auto; border: 1px dashed rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color: red;">div without border
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you! Position:absolute really fixes the problem